# Visual Studio 2008 Version Issues

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I currently have installed Visual Studio 2008, Version 9.0.30729.4462, and I am running into some fairly odd issues that I believe are all linked.

**1.** When building my solution, I get 5-10 of these output in the debug output:

`Project file contains ToolsVersion="4.0", which is not supported by this version of MSBuild. Treating the project as if it had ToolsVersion="3.5".`

All of the .csproj files of the projects contain `toolsversion="3.5"`.

**2.** When trying to access the Security tab in the project properties, I get the following error:

`Visual Studio was unable to determine the Code Access Security (CAS) permissions that are applicable to your project. The most likely cause is that your project references a strongly-named assembly that defines custom permissions, but that is not properly installed in the global assembly cache (GAC). To correct this, try the following:`

`1. Ensure that any custom permissions defining assemblies referenced by your project have been properly installed to the GAC. If any of these assemblies have been rebuilt or have had their version numbers modified, you must install the new assemblies in the GAC.`

`2. Restart Visual Studio.`

Looking for solutions on here indicate that this is a typically a toolsversion 4.0 problem; however, like I said, all of my projects have 3.5 set in the csproj files.

Where should I start troubleshooting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these problems were related to the toolsversion="4.0" issue. I have a lot of projects integrated into my solution, so I did a search for "toolsversion=" on my solution directory. It turns out a few of my .csproj project files were indeed set to 4.0. Once all of the projects were set to 3.5, the security tab came back, and I didn't receive any more errors when compiling.